# How to import mails by contacts from another Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, import

I want to import emails from another Gmail account by some specific email addresses? I have created another Gmail account for family and friends and I want all mails by them in my newly created account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to [create a filter](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579) and set all those specific email addresses in its conditions, and set it up to apply a new label (say, "Family"), to all messages, including existing ones.

Then you can follow [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/#!5521065) but instead of dragging all folders into your new account you would need to drag only the label "Family" which contains all your desired messages

EDIT: There's also "[Gmail Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/)" which claims might help with this, but I have not tried it.

Comment: In Gmail Backup there is no option to download only mail with a particular label but I think the first part is a viable option if your email client does not crash under the workload.